# Is there a way to take a payment for a product and put the money on hold until the service has been delivered?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a website where the customer would pay for the service, and than I need to put the payment on hold i.e. so that the business that's offering the service, don't get the money until they deliver the service.
Let's say that a business named X is selling a service on my website. Once a client buys the service from business X, I would want to hold the funds until the service has been delivered.

Is there a way to do this with WooCommerce or some other add on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Most Payment Gateways have the ability to either Capture or Authorize a payment. In this case - you just want to Authorize the payment. You can change this setting under Woocommerce > Settings > Payments > Your Payment Gateway. If you Authorize the payment, basically you just verify the charge will go through. You will still have to manually push the order through (when service is completed) either through Woocommerce or the gateway itself. Stripe, Paypal, Square and Authorize.net all have this option, I immagine others do too.